# How can aggregation be helpful in mitigating bias?

Tags: causality, treatment-effect, aggregation, causalimpact, selection-bias

I am working on the estimation assessing the impact of exposure to infrastructure (mainly schooling) on the number of children.

Since I do not have migration data, my colleague recommended that I aggregate the outcome at the level of distrcit to alleviate potential selection issues. I asked her how this works and she told me that it will account for internal migration across states, but honestly, I do not understand why this works.

I understand that people move to more developed district for some reason that could also affect education and fertility.

Could you help me grasp the concept behind this aggregating at the bigger unit than individual to solve the individual migration?

Appreciate your help in advance.